# Get Both Default locale translated value and Browser language translated value

Tags: ngx-translate

I'm trying to get Translated values for two locales for a given i18nkey.

Is there any way to pass required locales for a given key and get all values for the passed locales in ngx translate core translator service.

lets say Test key has de locale value as "Test DE" and Test key has EN locale value as "Test EN"

```
TranslateService.get('Test');

TranslateService.instant('Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

TranslateService.getTranslation(‘yourlocale’)